# How to filter closed user stories in the backlog?

Tags: azure-devops

I am new to using Azure DevOps and I currently have a backlog of user stories.
My problem is that I apply "closed status" filters and only tasks, bugs, etc. appear but no US is filtered out.
Can you help me?
Thanks

I am trying to apply filters in the backlog and to show the closed US but only other types of activities appear (tasks, bugs, etc.) see picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iX0oN.png)